# IE does not exit at end of Karma test run

Tags: internet-explorer, karma-runner

When using IE v10 (on win7-64) with the karma test runner, I notice that there is a new iexplorer.exe process after each karma run.  Anyone know how to get IE to exit?

I think this is the same issue being discussed in this github [thread](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/429) (even though the title is about capture -- which seems like a different thing to me).  I did try the two changes listed in the workaround/fix of that thread, but it made no difference. IE still does not exit.  So, this is basically a re-post of the question/issue from github.